# What is best design pattern to simplfy class with a lot of options to create it?

Tags: design-patterns, c++

I have a base class [for example]:

```cpp
class base
{
private:
    std::string name;

public:
    virtual void set_name(const std::string& name) = 0;
    virtual std::string get_name() const = 0;
};
```

- And 20 class inherited from it.
- And I have a UI (build with Qt) which user can select type of class to create it.

for handle this i use enumeration type [for example]:

```cpp
enum class types
{
    TYPE_1,
    TYPE_2,
    TYPE_3,
    ...
    TYPE_20,
};
```

and i end up with a long `switch-case` for type creation [for example]:

```cpp
switch(user_selected_mode)
{
case types::TYPE_1:
    return std::make_shared<type_1>();
    ...
case types::TYPE_2:
    return std::make_shared<type_2>();
}
```

i think you can imagine the ugly code in other section of code which depend of type of objects.

How could i make it cleaner ?

Comment: You have received a number of downvotes and the likely reason is that you are asking for the "best" way to do something and how to make the solution "cleaner". Both these words are only likely to result in opinions. People often downvote without providing any feedback. Your question is currently too broad to be answered well. Instead, you may wish to retract your question and then ask it again with more specific details about what you are attempting to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *creating* the objects, you could make a factory object, but in the end that's still going to have the same `switch` statement you currently have, just in a different object. Swings and roundabouts.

However, that's not going to fix this:

> i think you can imagine the ugly code in other section of code which depend of type of objects.

I can imagine what happens if everywhere you use one of these objects you've got to have a `switch` statement or similar based on the type of the object. What that says to me is that you've got a bigger problem with your design in that you're passing around what is (effectively) an empty object and then subverting the type system to work out what object type it *actually* is. I don't think we can fix that for you without more details as to *why* you think you need to do this rather than just passing round more specific types.